# WPF ScrollToTop vs ScrollToHome

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, scrollviewer

I was wondering what's the actual difference between [`ScrollViewer.ScrollToHome()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrolltohome) and [`ScrollViewer.ScrollToTop()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrolltotop).
Are they the same?

The documentation for both says:

> Scrolls vertically to the beginning of the ScrollViewer content.

I think it is very unusual to have two methods in the .NET Framework with different names, doing the same. Is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that ScrollViewer's can scroll both horizontally and vertically.

ScrollToTop - assumes that the ScrollViewer is vertical and goes to the beginning

ScrollToLeft - assumes that the ScrollViewer is horizontal and goes to the beginning

ScrollToHome - assumes neither and scrolls to the Top Left

Comment:  So the documentation of `ScrollToHome()` should be changed to: _Scrolls vertically and horizontally to the beginning of the ScrollViewer content._